# PYTHONPATH in OS X

Tags: python

I set PYTHONPATH variable on my Apple laptop a while ago.
I have checked /private/etc/profile config file. It is not there. Where else I could find it?

What other config file could be used to set the PYTHONPATH variable on OS X?

Comment: Maybe try `whereis python` in your console?

Comment: I am looking for the config file where PYTHONPATH environment variable is  set.

Comment: I might have a look at your `.bashrc` and/or your `.bash_profile` where the `export PATH` might be set up manually. In addition, you can check the path of Python by using `which python`.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/813/how-to-determine-where-an-environment-variable-came-from

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several config files that can be used to set **PYTHONPATH** in OS X:

The first is **profile** file which is located in hidden */private/etc/* folder:

```
/private/etc/profile
```

You can use the following syntax to set the variable there:

```
export MY_CUSTOM_ENV_VARIABLE="/Applications/MyApp/bin"
```

Other config files are `.cshrc`, `.bashrc` and `. bash_profile` which (thanks [albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3991125/albert) for your info) are located in user's home directory and based on your OS X might or might not be there:

```
/Users/username/.cshrc
/Users/username/.bashrc
/Users/username/.bash_profile
```

To set the environment variable in `.cshrc` file use the syntax below:

```
setenv MY_CUSTOM_ENV_VARIABLE /Applications/MyApp/bin
```

To set the environment variable using `.bash_profile` file use this syntax:

```
export MY_CUSTOM_ENV_VARIABLE=/Applications/MyApp/bin:$MY_CUSTOM_ENV_VARIABLE
```

In my case **PYTHONPATH** variable was set in `.bash_profile` file. And it was set with the following syntax:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/myModules:$PYTHONPATH
```