# how to set $PYTHONPATH on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5?

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-yosemite, pythonpath

I am using `terminal` which uses `-bash` shell

```
ps -p$$ -ocommand=    --->    -bash
```

echo $PATH returns:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/alex_fimm_dev/Desktop/Databases/Mongo/mongodb/bin:/Users/alex_fimm_dev/Desktop/Databases/Mongo/mongodb/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/tools:/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/platform-tools
```

echo $PYTHONPATH  -----> returns nothing

Need to set $PYTHONPATH to a /directory/of/choice

Unsuccessfully I have tried:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PATH:/directory/of/choice
```

Also write to: nano .bash_profile:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$(/directory/of/choice)
```

Also I have closed terminal in between to check for changes.

Comment: The `$(command substitution)` in the last attempt is definitely wrong; that will try to execute the text between the parentheses as a command, and return its output.

Answer (score 0):

export path in all following files:

```
private/etc/profile
```

like:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/directory/of/choice"
```

did the trick for me. As described in:

[PYTHONPATH in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39680157/pythonpath-in-os-x)

Comment: Only one of those is actually necessary.

Comment: edited answer to reflect relevant file to define environment variable in